# How would I use an existing certificate, etc., from our old app with the new PhoneGap Build app?

Tags: ios, mobile, certificate, phonegap-build

We have an existing app in the Apple store. I'm using PhoneGap Build to completely rebuild and replace it, rather than providing this PhoneGap Build app as a new app.

The kicker is the certificate, provisioning profile, and private key that Apple requires. We have all of this for our current app, and I'd like to use it in the new app. I made sure to make the new app bundle id the same as the current one.

I created a new development provisioning profile for myself, using the old certificate. If I upload all this to the new app with PhoneGap Build, it builds fine with no errors. But if I download it to the iPad or attempt to use it with the iPhone simulator on our Mac, it either won't install (iPad) or crashes when opening (sim).

I expect it's a signing problem, but all my attempts have failed and I feel in over my head. So here's the question: how do I use our current certificates, etc., with the new app? Is it possible? Can I create new dev/dist certificates and still update the current app in the Apple store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. I used the console in the iPhone Configuration Utility (iPCU) to watch the iPad as the app installed.

Turns out the iPad wasn't added to the Provisioning Profile, as I had thought it was. I created a new provisioning profile, adding my new dev certificate (another issue happening at the same time), and ensuring the iPad's UDID was included.

The PhoneGap Build app installs now, and it's not a signing problem.